# Can I travel to Ireland seperately on the BIVS Scheme after an initial trip to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian citizen. I have a UK Business C-Visa, and I have visited the UK before. Now I would like to visit Dublin (on a stopover) as a part of a separate trip to North America.

Can I make a trip to the Republic of Ireland on the BIVS scheme, or will I have to always enter the UK even on the second trip first, before I can make my way through to Dublin?

Comment: Do you plan *only* to stop in Dublin in transit, just to change planes, or are you hoping to leave the airport for a time to see the sights or for some similar purpose?

Comment: I hope to leave the airport to see the city for a day or two

Comment: Indications online point to BIVS and the related Irish short-stay visa waiver both requiring entry from the UK. I am commenting rather than answering because I can't speak from authority or experience and I can't do a very thorough search right now.

Comment: The main thing to remember with the British Irish Visa Scheme is that you must always enter the Common Travel Area via the country which issued the visa. Only then can you travel to the other country. For instance, if you have an Irish visa, then on each journey you must always clear immigration in Ireland before going to the UK, and if you have a UK visa you must always clear immigration in the UK before going to Ireland. But you may exit the Common Travel Area via either country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will I have to always enter the UK even on the second trip first before I can make my way through to Dublin?**

You have an entry clearance issued under the  British-Irish Visa Scheme (BIVS) and have entered the UK previously and want to know if this counts as meeting the requirements towards a separate trip to (or through) the Republic of Ireland.

No, once you leave the Common Travel Area, your BIVS 'resets' in the sense that the original requirements must be met again.  Your first entry must be in the country that issued the visa.

The standard 'go to' page for BIVS is [British-Irish Visa Scheme](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme), and this scheme is not *explicitly* addressed [in the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules) themselves. It is a policy created by [Ministerial Authorisation](https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/equality-authorisation-2014) by the previous government, and subject to withdrawal by either side.  Also note that information submitted to either side is made available to the [DHS](https://www.dhs.gov/).

Comment: Note: written statement last week by the Secretary of State for Northern Ireland http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201516/cmhansrd/cm160303/wmstext/160303m0001.htm  shows support by the current government

Comment: Looks like you gave the correct answer but reason i even brought this question is that I read up somewhere online that I could seperately visit Ireland later but cannot find that document again , I will keep searching